# Add "add to cart" button in WooCommerce

Tags: actions

I use the Mystile WooCommerce theme, where the "add to cart" buttons is removed by this code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
```

That is placed in this file `wp-content/themes/mystile/includes/theme-woocommerce.php`

I know I can just remove the piece of code, but is there a option, so the buttons still will appear, after the `theme-woocommerce.php` file is changed after next update?

I already tried to add this code to the my `functions.php` in my child theme.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
```

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're right about not doing this inside the theme file, also you have the right thing in mind putting this into your `functions.php`. Try the approach shown below, it's more you actually need, so pick what's fitting in your case.

**Code:**

```
    //remove add to cart buttons
    add_action( 'init', 'wpse124288_wc_remove_add_to_cart_buttons' );
    function wpse124288_wc_remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
        //add to cart button loop
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        //add to cart button single product
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }

    //(re)add add to cart buttons
    add_action( 'init', 'wpse124288_wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons' );
    function wpse124288_wc_readd_add_to_cart_buttons() {
        //add to cart button loop
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        //add to cart button single product
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
```